# C# error navigating to page

Tags: c#

when i click on the button `Knop1` i want to navigate to the page `ContentPage1` but I get a break mode error

Here is the code i am using:

```
namespace XamarinToets
{
    public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        async void Knop1Klik (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ContentPage1());
        }

        async void Knop2Klik(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //await Navigation.PushAsync(new ContentPage1());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can speak dutch and we're not going to help you with your test... TOETS = EXAM/TEST. Also if you want help be more specific. Oh and btw, change `knop` to `button` half your code is English and half is Dutch. That's bad practice

Comment: @Henk Disser you need to provide more information about the error